# how would I animate table cell width defined by php variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an online RPG style game website. I would love to be able to implement 'animated' health bars, however, I can not figure out how to go about doing so.. I know I will be using some form of java or jquery to perform the animation action. I've tried every way I can think of to make it work, but I just can't.

Basically in my code I have a variable that sets the HP bar (a table cell) to a specified width, I would like the table cell to shrink (or grow) to another variable defined in the code, say after battle damage is calculated.

How would I go about doing something like this, please help me!

This is an example of what I've tried:

---

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $( "health" ).animate({ "width": "-=100" }, "slow" );

 });
```

---

I have a table with a cell id set to health, I've tried id, class and name.

I hope this is specific enough, thank you.

Comment: It would be useful information to say that the animation function will happen after the attack form has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should prefix the id with a `#` if you want to use an id, or a dot `$( ".health" )` if you want to use a classname.

Like:

```
$( "#health" ).animate({ "width": "-=100" }, "slow" );
```

Or:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".health" ).animate({ "width": "-=100" }, "slow" );
});
```

For example:

```js
$( "#health" ).animate({ "width": "-=100" }, "slow" );
```

```css
td {width: 300px; background-color: #f00;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><td id="health">test</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: I copy pasted the css, html and script directly, still does not work for me.

Comment: If you have multiple `<tr><td id="health">test</td></tr>`, then you should use a classname instead of an id. `$( ".health" ).animate({ "width": "-=100" }, "slow" );` and `<table><tr><td class="health">test</td></tr><tr><td class="health">test</td></tr></table>`. You you see any errors in the log?

Comment: Can you test it using the `$( document ).ready`? ` like `$( document ).ready(function() {$( ".health" ).animate({ "width": "-=100" }, "slow" );});` or use an `#` if you use an id.

Answer (score 0):

```
There are multiple way to do animation in HTML, You have already tried with jQuery, syntax is right. But won't be possible with table. For animation like a bar would be zig-zag you would need Div or span.
```

Ref: [Click to see example](https://jsfiddle.net/Manish_sharma/gfh1xxhs/)
Hope you are looking for the same.

Comment: I copy pasted the css, html and script directly, still does not work for me.

Comment: Is there any error? make sure jQuery reference is there.

Comment: Reference is present, no errors, simply does nothing.

Comment: Selector Reference is missing in your code, you have css class on cell then use ".health", if have ID in case use "#health".

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#health").animate({
        width: ""
    }, {
        duration: 500,
    }); 
});